# Additional Bootstrap Responsive Size

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

Bootstrap provides the CSS file with the media queries to support an array of devices and ends with a min-width of 1200px which uses a grid that is 1170px wide. The problem is that in this particular case, the website in question requires an additional breakpoint at 1400px minimum and then to have a grid within that (say 1370px).

I've tried meddling with the numbers and been looking for a generator that I could find that'd simplify this, but I can't find one. I found a responsive grid generator, but I don't know what values to put in as it's not a generator shaped around Bootstrap.

All in all, I'm not so sure how to proceed forth in doing this and would love some input!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should add this or search the archive bootstrap-resposive.css

```
@media (min-width: 1400px) {
    #yourid {
        width : 1370px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Raul. - I know how to do that but Bootstrap has a grid and so I don't know if someone knew of a generator I could use to get the sizes for each column and whatnot.

Answer (score 0):

try this: [Customize](http://getbootstrap.com/customize/)

I don't know if you may add another media query in that way though it is pretty cool to check out either way. Hope this helps.